# Hotkey for copying text as you type

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

When I'm programming I often use copy and paste, which requires me to grab the mouse, highlight the text, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (I'm using Windows BTW). Is there any hotkey or solution out there for a keyboard short cut that I could press and have it start copying each character I type? It would be such a godsend to get rid of that whole highlighting mess!

Comment: "When I'm programming I often use copy and paste" - this raises a red flag for me. How often do you do this? You shouldn't really have to copy and paste so often that you need special copy/paste methods to speed up your programming. Code with lots of duplicated stuff is often bloated and hard to maintain.

Comment: I just don't like retyping variable names and function calls that I'm going to use right away again. I actually wanted this for some SQL stuff I'm doing currently, but I think I could just use select word for this type of stuff. I understand the importance of reducing code duplication, and my inquiry has nothing to do with copying huge segments of code.

Comment: you would also need another key to indicate when to stop copying, wouldn't you?  this is an interesting idea, it might end up being less keystrokes than highlighting with something like ctrl-shift-arrowkey or possibly even less than the equivalent action in VI.

Comment: If I made it my self, I was thinking it would stop copying after you moved the cursor it'd stop copying and would empty the copy/clipboard/whatever it uses when you press the hotkey/shortcut again. I guess how you'd use it depends on what you'd use most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably develop a quick application that does that in VB (via global hotkey listener). But for me, I am a keyboard shortcut nerd, and I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd> /<kbd>→</kbd>  to navigate the caret through "words" (sometimes that means every non-alphanumeric token, but it varies on the IDE you're using) that I want to copy--It's much faster than <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd> /<kbd>→</kbd>. I also use this combination frequently: <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, which is a quick way to select and copy the whole line.

I can see where you're coming from with the "toggling copy", but I think using the full extent of the keyboard, while primitive, is the best and most practical.

Comment: I'm interested in the idea of developing a quick solution in VB. Sounds like what I'll have to do to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd>  and <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>→</kbd>  will select text forward and backup.

Most editors have a lot more (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd>  for selecting to next word boundary for instance) but depends on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long your code is, you can always do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the line, providing that you're at the end of the line. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> would select the preceding line if you're at the beginning of the line, etc.